# Required value missing - sourceValue

Tags: reporting, ant, deployment

I am receiving this error while deploying Reports through ANT.

[image: Type: Report, Error Msg: required field is missing: sourceValues]

After investigation I found that the below 'backets' tag don't have tag 'sourceValues'.

[image]

However the thing is that I have just got these report files by ANT retrieve command from the same ORG. and Have not modified any file.

Is it related to version issue ? or something else ?

I am using
ANT version:  1.9.3
package.xml version: 30.0

Comment: ,You are missing field named Sourcevalues in your destination instance .Is your orgs in sync with fields ?

Comment: Its all being done in same ORG. Different ORGs not involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing the following:
<values>
      <value>Out</value>
</values>
with:
<values>
  <sourceValues>
    <sourceValue>Out</sourceValue>
  </sourceValues>
  <value>Out</value>
</values>

Do this for all <values> tags in the bucket fields that don't have the <sourceValues> tag. This worked for me and I was able to deploy using Ant.

I don't know why this happened but I just wanted to let you know what worked for me. Hope this helps you.

Comment: This is not the exact answer as I wanted to find out why that tag is missing when retrieved by ANT. However Marking this as 'answer' since its provide the way to move-on.

Answer (score 2):

[This help article](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000205894) explains that this error occurs when you have a bucketed field that does not contain any values. The resolution is to either delete the bucketed field or modify it by adding some values to it.